# Update performance cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a SQL table thats being modelled for cassandra to run different queries.

Person

```
 id primary key,
 fname,
 lname,
 age
```

All the fields can be queried so im creating multiple tables

Person_fname

```
 fname primary key,
 lname,
 age,
 id
```

Person_lname

```
 lname primary key,
 fname,
 age,
 id
```

Person_age

```
 age primary key,
 lname,
 age,
 fname
```

Questions :-

```
1. If first_name is updated for a particular person, Should I need to update all the tables?
2. What would be the performance impact in CASSANDRA because of this update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your questuion #1, since you mean updating column values in different tables, no doubt, you have to update all the tables.

For question #2, first you could do batch update, and the batch update performance on several tables is best when their partition is on the same node, one way to ensure this is to use the same column as partition key of these tables, e.g. person_id.

But your table design above for cassandra looks completely wrong. One thing in cassandra you need to remember is for the same primary key value, you could only have one row in a table, and insert or update with the same value of the primary key, has the same insertOrUpdate effect.

e.g. for your second table, it is not possible to have two rows with a same fname value 'tom'. If you insert two rows with fname='tom', the second insert row actually does update on the row inserted by the first insert.

Comment: many thanks..I agree,I added the id part of primary key for all the tables..Does it look good now?

Comment: also, this Person table has probably has 10 attributes and the user would like to query against all the attributes and im planning to create 10 tables for each type of query..As cassandra recommends design table for different queries..Does it really makes sense?

Comment: use the id column as primary key is correct. But to create 10 tables only for query by different columns doesn't make much sense. Yes, cassandra doesn't allow query on all the fields, for you case, consider to use Solr or Elasticearch together with Cassandra. When insert or update records, also update the index in Solr/Elasticsearch for this row so that you could search freely with Solr/Elasticsearch search API.

Comment: Our's transaction involves more inserts and updates..Is it advisable to directly use Elastic search as the backend..THe reason im hesistating to ES directly is because its not good for transactions...Also, is there a nice plugin to sync cassandra and elasticsearch..I saw datastax but thats not a free version

Comment: We do use Solr since we use the DataStax commercial version. For elasticsearch, I guess [elasticsearch-cassandra-river](https://github.com/srecon/elasticsearch-cassandra-river) is what you need. To only use ES might not be a good idea coz you don't really need to index all the columns for all the tables. And the performance/stalibity/scalibility of cassandra is better.